# SHOW TABLES only shows tables starting with a space mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some code that needs to get a list of all of the tables in a database with a certain column equaling a certain thing. However, using the `SHOW TABLES` MySQL code is only listing tables that start with a space. Here is my code...

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW FULL TABLES IN `db`") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
while ($word = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $word = $word[0];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `db`.`$word` WHERE col='$val'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
    while ($col = mysql_fetch_array($result)) echo "<li><a nav='$word' title='View $word'>$word</a></li>";
}
```

For some reason, the first `mysql_query()` is only returning one result, which happens to be a table beginning with a space. (It is the only table starting with a space in the whole thing)
Edit: I just realized that I left out the line of code that turned $word from an array into a string... it's in there now.

Comment: Maybe `$word` contains a space when you fetch it from the database?

Comment: `$word` is an array, you sure you don't have `db.$word[0]` in your sql ?

Comment: $word is from the first mysql_query(). The while loop is going through the results, and assigning them to $word. The problem is coming from the first mysql_query(). It is only listing the tables that have a space in the beginning.

Comment: Hint: Use the OO interface of mysqli. It makes it more easy to have multiple queries inside one's code in parallel.

Comment: Never really used MySQLi, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Maybe the data *in the database* contains spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-writing $result (your table list) inside the loop.

After the first iteration, $result will contain a list of fields from the first table.

Comment: I know that I am overwriting $result, but the only variable that I need from the first loop is $word.

Comment: The 2nd time through the loop, won't that look at the first table again?

Comment: I did some tests with a simple 'echo $word' right after the $word=$word[0], and it still only returned the one table.

Comment: Also, I can't see where you're using $col?

Comment: Oh yes, $col is not actually needed in the current code, although I left it there in case I need it later.

Comment: $word will contain the 1st table only, you're hard-coding the index. You need a variable that increments every time through the loop & I'd change the 2nd $result to something else ($columns), if only to avoid confusion.

Comment: The SHOW TABLES query fetches a list of the tables in a database, and then the array returned by mysql_fetch_array contains all of the tables in the database (well... it should...), and then index 0 of each of those arrays is the table name. So that is why the index is hard-coded.

Comment: Wooh! That was weird. I just changed the second $result to $cols and now it works! Thanks!